# Как правильно изменять состояние redux, react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Начал изучать redux, так и не понял как праильно надо менять состояние(store).

Прочитал несколько статей везде говорится надо использовать чистые функции.
Что такое чистые функции я знаю, но так и не понял как менять состояние

Сейчас делаю так

```
function reducer(state, action){

  switch (action.type) {

    case 'LOGGED': {

      return {
        isLogged : true,
        user: action.user 
      }

    };
   
    // another case s


    default: return state;

  }

}

export default reducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Лучше практиковать `redux` с простым CRUD.

Вот пример, который вы можете посмотреть и использовать в вашем проекте.
Как установить `redux` и применить `store` в компонентах.

https://github.com/madly0894/react_redux_crud

Answer (score 0):

Вы все правильно делаете только нужно скопировать весь state:

```
case 'LOGGED':
      return {
        ...state,
        isLogged : true,
        user: action.user 
      }
```